# Updating Highcharts realtime using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, highcharts, socket.io

I'm making a dashboard using node.js, socket.io and highcharts.

I want my chart to update dynamically on receiving a request from socket.io.

How do I do that?

Here is my client side code,

```
<script>
var socket=io();
var sales=0;
var e1tcount=0;
var e1scount=0;
var e2tcount=0;
var e2scount=0;

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: function(){

                        socket.on('response', function(arr){
                            $('#c1').html(arr[0]);
                            sales+=arr[2];
                            $('#sales').html(sales);

                            if(arr[1]=="CT")
                            {
                                e1tcount++; 
                                $('#e1t').html(e1tcount);
                                e1scount+=arr[2];
                                $('#e1s').html(e1scount);
                                //Tried this, doesnt work 
                                var sold=chart.series[0].data[0].y;
                                chart.series[0].data[0].update(sold+1);
                            }
                            if(arr[1]=="AB")
                            {
                                e2tcount++;
                                $('#e2t').html(e2tcount);
                                e2scount+=arr[2];
                                $('#e2s').html(e2scount);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Event 1', 'Event 2']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            colors: ['#FFCC99','#3366CC'],
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sold',
                data: [0, 0]
            }, {
                name: 'Available',
                data: [20, 20]
            }]
        });
    });




</script>
```

Intially the number of tickets is 20, but as soon as I post data using curl, the number of sold tickets should increase and available tickets should decrease, depending on the event.

How do I go about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And what error do you have in console? ;) I guess somethng about 'cannot read property of udefined'. You need to create chart variable first, then you can use that variable, right? So:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    var chart = this; // create chart variable for future use
                    socket.on('response', function(arr){
```

Then that code should work:

```
                            //Tried this, doesnt work 
                            var sold=chart.series[0].data[0].y;
                            chart.series[0].data[0].update(sold+1);
```

If this won't be enough, then copy&paste errors here.